# Versioning of customer specific files

Tags: git

I have project with following structure:

```
classes/
  - core/        # core files
  - override/    # drop in replacements for specific customer
```

Then I have on core repo with everything except `override/` folder and one repo customer with just `override/` folder.

For deployment I clone core repository and add customer repository as second remote and pull. That works great except it merges the customer overrides to the main repo. This is really inconvenient for development as I have to separate those repositories after.

I also looked into git submodules, but I couldn't make it work. It still needed to have many customer folders (albeit empty) in main repo. Also I didn't managed to fetch just one submodule.

What is the best practice of versioning such project?

Comment: git has this thing called "branches"

Comment: I know, but how to keep those core files synchronized between so many branches?  (tens and hundreds)

Comment: Just `merge --ff` (if your "git policy" allows for fast forward) before each compile or whatever

Comment: Dear, you're right. I was just really over-thinking it. Thanks a lot.